# Can someone help me with this one ? Why I am getting Output Twice

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, after-trigger, basics

**This is how my trigger looks:**

```
trigger problem5 on Contact (after update)
{
    
    if(Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        id currentID ;
        if(Trigger.isupdate)
        {
            double percentage= 0;
            double positiveDead= 0;
            double total = 0;
            
            
            for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
            {
                currentID = c.AccountID;
            }
            System.debug('Current Id : '+currentID);
                        
            positiveDead += [SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :currentID And Dead__c = true];
            total+= [SELECT count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId= :currentID];
            
            System.debug('Positive Dead :'+positiveDead+'\nTotal :'+total);
            
            //Calculate Percnetage : 
            percentage = (positiveDead/total)*100;
            System.debug('Percentage :'+percentage);
            
            //if Greater Than 70 Update Need Intel field :
            if(percentage >= 70)
            {
                Account acc = [SELECT Need_Intel__c from Account where id = :currentID limit 1];
                acc.Need_Intel__c = true;
                update acc ;
                System.debug('Need intel set to '+true);
            }
            else
            {
                Account acc = [SELECT Need_Intel__c from Account where id = :currentID limit 1];
                acc.Need_Intel__c = false;
                update acc ;
                System.debug('Need intel set to '+false);
            }
           
        }
    }

}
```

**What I am trying to do:**
I am updating the need_intel value to true if the 70% or more of contacts related to it are dead.

**Code Works fine but in Debug Log I am getting this:**

[image]

**Why I am getting output Twice and also why it's showing percentage 0 and if 0 why it is not updating need intel value ??**

THANKS IN ADVANCE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different Ids, so two records are being updated. Presumably, both records were correctly updated. However, your code is not bulk-safe, it will fail during large data loads. You can fix your code as:

```
trigger problem5 on Contact (after update) {
    Map<Id, Integer> aliveCount = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    Map<Id, Integer> deadCount = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
    Account[] accountUpdates = new Account[0];
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.AccountId != null) {
            accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
            alivecount.put(record.AccountId, 0);
            deadCount.put(record.AccountId, 0);
            accountUpdates.add(new Account(Id=record.AccountId, Need_Intel__c=false));
        }
    }
    for(AggregateResult result:[
        SELECT COUNT(Id) Number, AccountId AccountId, Dead__c Dead
        FROM Contact 
        WHERE AccountId = :accountIds GROUP BY AccountId, Dead__c
    ]) {
        Id accountId = (Id)result.get('AccountId');
        Integer contactCount = (Integer)result.get('Number');
        Boolean isDead = (Boolean)result.get('Dead');
        (isDead?deadCount:aliveCount).put(accountId,contactCount);
    }
    for(Account record: accountUpdates) {
        Decimal aliveValue = aliveCount.get(record.Id);
        Decimal deadValue = deadCount.get(record.Id);
        Decimal totalCount = aliveValue + deadValue;
        record.Need_Intel__c = totalCount != 0 && deadValue/totalCount > 0.70;
    }
    update accountUpdates;
}
```